# Merging columns to create a date with a header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header

I'm using a large climate file where there's a YYYY, MM, DD columns. I want to merge these to create a date column, while keep all the original data in the dataset.

I have managed to do this so far which gets me almost what I want but I can't seem to get a header in the date column.

```
climate = pd.read_csv(r'R:\Climate\SILO\PatchedPoint\Current_csv\86090.csv')

climate.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'ignore')
climate_nozero = climate.drop([0])

climate2 = climate_nozero.rename(columns = {'YYYY':'Year','MM':'Month','DD':'Day'})

index = climate2.apply(lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime("{0} {1} {2}".format(x['Year'],x['Month'], x['Day']), "%Y %m %d"),axis=1) 

climate3 = pd.concat([index, climate2], axis=1)
```

I tried

```
climate4 = climate3.rename(columns = {'0':'Date'})
```

to change the header but it does nothing

[I've added the output table that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4uid.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), but rename columns is necessary:

```
data = {"YYYY": ["2010", "2012", "2015"], 
        "MM": ["5", "10", "12"], 
        "DD": ["1", "2", "3"],
        "foo": range(3)}

climate_nozero = pd.DataFrame(data)

climate2 = climate_nozero.rename(columns = {'YYYY':'Year','MM':'Month','DD':'Day'})

climate2.index = pd.to_datetime(climate2[['Year','Month','Day']])
print (climate2)
            Year Month Day  foo
2010-05-01  2010     5   1    0
2012-10-02  2012    10   2    1
2015-12-03  2015    12   3    2
```

And then if want remove columns:

```
climate2 = climate2.drop(['Year','Month','Day'], axis=1)
print (climate2)
            foo
2010-05-01    0
2012-10-02    1
2015-12-03    2
```

If want datetime column:

```
climate2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(climate2[['Year','Month','Day']])
print (climate2)
   Year Month Day  foo       date
0  2010     5   1    0 2010-05-01
1  2012    10   2    1 2012-10-02
2  2015    12   3    2 2015-12-03
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your date columns are strings, you can use [`assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) like this:

```
df.assign(date = pd.to_datetime(df['YYYY'] + "-" + df['MM'] + "-" + df['DD']))

   YYYY  MM DD  foo       date
0  2010   5  1    0 2010-05-01
1  2012  10  2    1 2012-10-02
2  2015  12  3    2 2015-12-03
```

Data:

```
data = {"YYYY": ["2010", "2012", "2015"], 
        "MM": ["5", "10", "12"], 
        "DD": ["1", "2", "3"],
        "foo": range(3)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

the concat and rename I would recommend directly assigning the column to a named field in your dataframe. I think the below should work as a replacement for your bottom two lines:

```
climate2["Date"] = climate2.apply(lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime("{0} {1} {2}".format(x['Year'],x['Month'], x['Day']), "%Y %m %d"),axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks this works, then I just made the Date column the index.